# Sort mongodb query on multiple fields

Tags: mongodb, nosql, mongodb-query

I would like to sort a mongodb query that search for bloggers.

Here the document structure (simplified) of a Blogger :

```
{
  posts : {
    hashtags : [{
      hashtag : String,
      weight  : Number
    }]
  },
  globalMark : Number
}
```

People can search bloggers via an input text. Eg: They can write "fashion travel" and click on search button.

I would like as result to show up Bloggers who have posts that contain hashtags that match /fashion/i and /travel/i, sorted by relevancy. The relevancy depends on the globalMark and hashtag weight.

I know how to show up them skipping hashtag weight but don't know how to include this weight in my query....

Here my current query :

```
Blogger.find({
  "$and" : [{
    "posts.hashtags.hashtag" : {$regex: /fashion/i}
  }, {
    "posts.hashtags.hashtag" : {$regex: /travel/i}
  }]
})
.sort("-globalMark")
```

How can I handle this weight ?
BIG THANKS !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made it using mongodb aggregation and $project pipeline stage. Basically $project let you modify result doc so I have used it to build a score regarding different fields then sort the aggregation on this built score.

Here the doc :
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/

Answer (score 0):

First think: MongoDB is not a for search  with like operator (if your data is big you will have some latency).
Second think: hashtags value need to be object or objects in array
Third: You can use

```
db.collectionName.find({
    $and: [
        {"posts.hashtags.hashtag" : {$regex: /fashion/i}},
        {"posts.hashtags.hashtag" : {$regex: /travel/i}}
    ]
}).sort({
    globalMark: 1, "posts.hashtags.weight": 1
})
```

Comment: Hey ! Thanks !!! Unfortunately it doesn't work... If one Blogger has a post with hashtag "fashion" and weight = 10 BUT another Blogger has a post with hastag "fashion" and weight = 4 but other random hashtags that have weight above 10 then this Blogger will be showed before the first one. :(

Comment: sort in mongo with two fields working like this: at first sorting with `globalMark` and then `posts.hashtags.weight`. if you want a DESC sorting for `posts.hashtags.weight` please use `"posts.hashtags.weight": -1`. If I can do anything else let me know

Comment: Thanks but I mean I would like to sort only on hashtags weight that match my $regex : something like {keySort: {"posts.hashtags.weight": 1}, condition: {"posts.hashtags.hashtag": {$regex: /fashion/i}}}

Comment: I have figure out it is perhaps better to review my docs and append all hashtags in a single string then use MongoDB Text search feature with score sorting...

Comment: if you will share your collection finished structure I will try to help you:)

Comment: FYI, I have made it using aggregation and $project to build a score then sort by this score :D ! Thanks for your help !